# How to sort by ratio while avoiding division by zero?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

Consider a class Team, with class variables 'wins' and 'losses'. I wish to sort an array of Teams by the win:loss ratio, such that:

5:0 > 3:0 > 1:0 > 3:1 > 5:5 > 3:3 > 1:3 > 0:1 > 0:3 > 0:5

I already have a (partial) hacked together solution that I'm not happy with, and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner/more elegant/simpler way to solve this problem.

```
def ratio
    if @losses == 0 then 
        return 1000000+@wins
    end
    if @wins == 0 then
        return 0-@losses
    end
    return @wins/@losses
end
```

(This does not fix 5:5 > 3:3)

Which would be in the Team class and could be used like this:

```
teams.sort! { |a, b| b.ratio <=> a.ratio }
```

What is the simplest way to solve this? (Solutions does not have to be Ruby, I'm happy with anything that is OO)

Comment: I think the logic is complex enough to not want to assign a single number (ratio) and instead define ordering on the win/loss data structure itself

Comment: I wouldn't suggest trying to convert the win/loss ratio to a number that you can sort by. You wouldn't try to sort strings that way, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak Ruby, but a Python approach which would give your desired results would use a tuple for a key (in the decorate-sort-undecorate "Schwartzian transform" idiom.)

For example, you could rank by win fraction, then number of wins, then (negative) number of losses, which would give your desired ordering:

```
>>> wl = [[3, 0], [3, 1], [0, 5], [3, 3], [0, 3], [5, 5], [1, 3], [5, 0]]
>>> 
>>> def rank(wl):
...     win, loss = wl
...     return (1.0*win/(win+loss) if win+loss > 0 else 0), win, -loss
... 
>>> sorted(wl, key=rank)
[[0, 5], [0, 3], [1, 3], [3, 3], [5, 5], [3, 1], [3, 0], [5, 0]]
>>> sorted(wl, key=rank)[::-1]
[[5, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [5, 5], [3, 3], [1, 3], [0, 3], [0, 5]]
```

I don't know what the Ruby equivalent is, unfortunately, but I gather that there's a `sort_by` method floating around somewhere.

Comment: Indeed, [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).`wl.sort_by{|win,loss| [win.to_f/(win+loss > 0 ? win+loss : 0), win, -loss]}` is the Ruby equivalent (http://codepad.org/12rwnlmB).

Comment: Do you need the 3rd item? If two teams have the same winning percentage and the same number of wins, they necessarily have the same number of losses.

Comment: @chepner: no, they don't.  Consider (0,3) and (0,5) -- they both have the same win percentage (0%) and the same number of wins (0), but they have a different number of losses.

Comment: @DSM: oh, of course. That's what I get for trying to use my brain on Friday afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining a method to use with `sort_by`, why not override `<=>` so that it handles the comparison, and then you can avoid creating a number, and instead do something like

```
def <=>(other)
  if losses == 0
    -1
  elsif other.losses == 0
    1
  else
    # do ratio logic here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a win percentage for each team and sort for that.  Within each win percentage, you should sort by total games played, taking sure to decide if total games is good or bad depending on if the team's overall win percentage is less than or greater than 50%.

Comment: This may be the best approach if you must boil it down to a single number for ranking. But do we want 1:0 > 99:1 ?

Comment: According to the question, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
(@wins * 3 + 1) / (@losses * 3 + 2)

5:0 8.00
3:0 5.00
3:1 2.00
5:5 0.94
3:3 0.91
1:3 0.36
0:3 0.09
0:5 0.06
```

Comment: Is there any logic to `+ 1` and `+ 2`? Just because they're the simplest numbers that work?

Comment: They need to be nonzero to allow sorting `5:0 > 0:5` and different to allow sorting `5:5 > 3:3` but apart from that I picked them (and the `3`) arbitrarily.

Comment: Make sure you put enough comments so someone does not spend sleepless nights behind the mystery of 1, 2 and 3 :)

Comment: Yeah, ideally you would test it against a larger dataset and pick some values that work well for you.

Comment: i admire the simplicity of this method.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this worked, but it does not. Consider the the case 1:0 and 7:1, which evaluate to 2 and 4.4. Thus, this will not sort by ratio. I will update the original order spec.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer 7:1 to 1:0, but I've since found another anomaly anyway, for instance n:2n always evaluates to 0.5 with my calculation making no help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments above, I agree that a single sortable number would work well.  Perhaps something like:

```
def win_loss_ranking
  (@wins *2 ) - (@losses * 2) + (@wins + @losses)
end
```

this gives you a number that takes into account games played as well as wins and losses.  so in your case where there are 5:5 and 3:3, the 5:5 would have a win_loss_ranking of 10 and the 3:3 team would have a 6.

Comment: That is `3*@wins-@losses` according to my rusty algebra ; (5 wins, 5 losses) outscores (3 wins, 0 losses).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ratio (in the sense relevant to your purpose) would be monotone increasing with respect to the **difference**.</strike> Why not implement it using difference?

```
class Team
  def difference; @wins - @losses end
end

teams.sort!{|a, b| a.difference <=> b.difference}
```

Comment: Consider 1:0 and 7:1, which when sorted would not be ordered by ratio.

Comment: What is your expecting result? You want it not ordered, or ordered in some way?

Comment: Ordered by "ratio", with examples: 5:0 > 3:0 > 1:0 > 3:1 > 5:5 > 3:3 > 1:3 > 0:1 > 0:3 > 0:5. When sorting by the difference, 3:1 > 1:0. I should have included 1:0 and 0:1 in the original example.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Ruby version of [DSM's Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530620/298607).

Given:

```
> a=["0:1", "5:0", "3:3", "0:3", "1:3", "3:0", "1:0", "0:5", "5:5", "3:1"]
```

You can do:

```
def rank(wl)
    w, l = wl.split(/:/).map(&:to_f)
    [w/(w+l > 0 ? -(w+l) : 0), -w, l]
    end
> a.sort { |a,b| rank(a)<=>rank(b) }
["5:0", "3:0", "1:0", "3:1", "5:5", "3:3", "1:3", "0:1", "0:3", "0:5"]
```

Then if you wanted to have that in oo format, might be something like:

```
class Wl 
   def initialize(win_loss)
       @wl=win_loss
   end
   def wl()
      @wl
   end 
   def rank()
      w, l = @wl.split(/:/).map(&:to_f)
      [w/(w+l > 0 ? -(w+l) : 0), -w, l]
   end
   def to_s
       @wl
   end
   def inspect
       @wl 
   end 
   def <=>(other)
      rank <=> other.rank
   end 
end

> b=a.map{ |e| Wl.new(e) }
[0:1, 5:0, 3:3, 0:3, 1:3, 3:0, 1:0, 0:5, 5:5, 3:1]
> b.sort
[5:0, 3:0, 1:0, 3:1, 5:5, 3:3, 1:3, 0:1, 0:3, 0:5]
```